# Pandas dataframe remove rows by aggregated data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 9, 3], [1, 5, 6], [2, 1, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 9 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 9 |

I want to keep 'a' iff the sum of 'b's under the same 'a' is greater than 10.

For this case, the desire output is:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 9 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 6 |

My solution is as below:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 9, 3], [1, 5, 6], [2, 1, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
tmp_ = test1.groupby("a").sum().reset_index()
test1[test1["a"].isin(tmp_[tmp_["b"]>10]["a"].to_list())]
```

I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: You probably don't need that `np.array`

Answer (score 4):

Group by 'a' and use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html?highlight=series%20groupby%20transform#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform)

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 9, 3], [1, 5, 6], [2, 1, 9]]),
                     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

b_sum_by_a = test1.groupby('a')['b'].transform('sum') 

test1 = test1[b_sum_by_a > 10] 

>>> test1 

   a  b  c
0  1  9  3
1  1  5  6
```